# Possible to get more than 5 tags for /search? Or to use or-logic, for tags, in /questions?

Tags: support, api, tags, search

This is the query I want to run:

```
/2.1/search?pagesize=100&page=1&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=linux,ubuntu,bash,linux-mint,mint,linux-distributions,linux-distro,archlinux,&site=superuser&filter=.Ericv1w97*YhCWfY.uMVBr(o
```

Is it possible to search for more than 5 tags?

I would use `/questions`, but since it treats tags as AND instead of OR, I don't have any other option. Or do I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `search` path already allows more than 5 tags, and it uses ***OR*** logic.  From [the docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search):

> tagged and nottagged are **semi-colon delimited** list of tags. At least 1 tag in tagged will be on each returned question if it is passed, making it **the OR equivalent** of the AND version of tagged on /questions.

(bold added)

Note that tags are separated with a semicolon, not a comma.  So, you would use:

```
/2.1/search?pagesize=100&page=1&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=linux;ubuntu;bash;linux-mint;mint;linux-distributions;linux-distro;archlinux&site=superuser&filter=.Ericv1w97*YhCWfY.uMVBr(o
```

**[which works fine (try it)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#page=100&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=linux%3Bubuntu%3Bbash%3Blinux-mint%3Bmint%3Blinux-distributions%3Blinux-distro%3Barchlinux&filter=!9hnGswtTz&site=superuser&run=true).**